# using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; is not working; Release error

Tags: c#, winforms, project-reference

Error Message:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Reference file is included in reference folder.
Project is running on debug, but not working on release mode.

Comment: Check your csproj file; do you have a MySql package reference? and is it perhaps in an `<ItemGroup>` with a `Condition` that checks the configuration? If so: move it to an `<ItemGroup>` that *doesn't* have a `Condition` check

Answer (score 0):

use;

```
using MySql;
```

- Rebuild your project and upload all bin DLLs
- this then reupload mysql.dll and check the result
- the namespace for mysql is MySQL.Datas dans MySQL.Types (something like, check to documentation in your mysql connector install path).

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer,

1. Right Click on the MySQL in `Reference` section
2. Select properties
3. Change `copyLocal` as `true`
4. Rebuild the project.

[image]